# Migración de proyecto laravel8/php7.4 a laravel9/php8.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php8, laravel-9

Estoy actualizando mi proyecto a la versión 9 de laravel y por ende a la versión 8 de php. Todo parece fluir a excepción de las consultas que utilizan un tipo de dato fecha.

El problema con las columnas de tipo fecha es que automaticamente les cambia el formato.

La versión 8 la tengo montada en una instancia EC2(AMI) de AWS y se conecta a un RDS.

Para la versión 9, estoy haciendo pruebas locales con homestead/vagrant y conectadome a una BD en mi equipo fisico. (mssql)

- Este es el diseño de mi tabla tblCatTask:

```
dblTask => bigint
strTask=> varchar(255)
datStartDate  => date
```

Este es el primer registro en la tabla:

```
dblTask strTask datStartDate 
1        "Quote" "2023-02-20"
```

Mi Modelo

```
    class Task extends Model {     
        use HasFactory;     
        protected $table = 'dbo.tblCatTask';     
        protected $primaryKey = 'dblTask';    
        public $timestamps = false;  
    }
```

Llamada en TaskController

```
    class TaskController extends Controller {     
           public function index()     {
             return Task::first();
```

Resultado en pantalla:

```
App\Models\MasterTiming\Task {#4690 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/PagesController.php:20
  #connection: "sqlsrv"
  #table: "dbo.tblCatTask"
  #primaryKey: "dblTask"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:3[▼
    "dblTask" => 1
    "strTask" => "Quote"
    "datStartDate" => "Feb 20 2023 12:00:00:AM"  
  ]
  #original: array:3 [▼
    "dblTask" => 1
    "strTask" => "Quote"
    "datStartDate" => "Feb 20 2023 12:00:00:AM"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
```

¿Porque la propiedad datStartDate es diferente al valor/formato en la base de datos?
Estoy migrando mi proyecto en vagrant
de php 7.4/laravel8 a php8.2/laravel9

NOTA: Solo sucede con los tipos de dato DATE, el problema no se presenta con los tipos DATETIME

Answer (score 1):

Si el campo en tu tabla fuera un varchar, laravel de mostraría ese contenido tal cual. Como es de tipo DATE, al hidratar el registro en base de datos para poblar una instancia del modelo Task, lo castea implícitamente usando la librería Carbon.

A su vez, Carbon parsea la fecha y a la hora de mostrarla en pantalla la convierte a desde su valor interno a un string, usando un formato por defecto.

Si tú quieres que la fecha que te entrega por pantalla tenga otro formato, defínela en la propiedad $casts del modelo

```
class Task extends Model {
   protected $casts {
       'datStartDate' => 'date'  // también puedes usar 'datetime'
   }
}
```

Pero, como te dije, eso sólo afecta al formateo que Carbon utilizará cuando se muestre en pantalla. Internamente el valor de la fecha es independiente a su representación como texto.

Tú podrías hacer

```
$task = Task::first();

// startDate es una instancia de Carbon, no un texto.
$task->datStartDate=$task->startDate->subDays(5);
$task->save();
```

El registro en base de datos será la fecha menos cinco días, pero, si te fijas, en esa operación nunca salió a colación el formato, todo se hizo con el objeto interno que Carbon parseó cuando se hidrató el modelo.

El dato en mysql seguirá teniendo el formato de siempre.